# Airflow PostgresToGoogleCloudStorageOperator authentication error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, airflow

Is there any documentation regarding how to authenticate with google cloud storage through an airflow dag?

I am trying to use airflow's PostgresToGoogleCloudStorageOperator to upload the results from a query to google cloud storage. However I am getting the below error.

```
{gcp_api_base_hook.py:146} INFO - Getting connection using `google.auth.default()` since no key file is defined for hook.

{taskinstance.py:1150} ERROR - 403 POST https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/my_test_bucket123/o?uploadType=multipart: ('Request failed with status code', 403, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>)
```

I have configured "gcp_conn_id" in the airflow UI and provided the json from my service account key but still getting this error.

Below is the entire dag file

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.postgres_to_gcs_operator import PostgresToGoogleCloudStorageOperator

DESTINATION_BUCKET = 'test'
DESTINATION_DIRECTORY = "uploads"




dag_params = {
    'dag_id': 'upload_test',
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 7, 7),
    'schedule_interval': '@once',
}

with DAG(**dag_params) as dag:
    upload = PostgresToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
        task_id="upload",
        bucket=DESTINATION_BUCKET,
        filename=DESTINATION_DIRECTORY + "/{{ execution_date }}" + "/{}.json",
        sql='''SELECT * FROM schema.table;''',
        postgres_conn_id="postgres_default",
        gcp_conn_id="gcp_default"
    )
```

Comment: What value you have in scopes for the gcp connection?

Comment: I did not put anything in scopes, I put the json from my service account key in the Keyfile JSON field.

Comment: I think you still need to define scopes. There is difference between authentication and permission. You can be authenticated but lack permission to access a specific service. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/connections/gcp.html

Comment: Could you please confirm if you are using the following [guidelines](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/connections/gcp.html#authenticating-to-google-cloud) to authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. There is this very nice documentation with examples for Google Connection:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/connections/gcp.html

Also GCP has this very nice overview of all the authentication methods you can use:

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authentication-method